# Java program won't finish method - exits after a for loop with no errors instead

Tags: java, methods

edit: As I was writing this post, I made my code simpler (lost arrays entirely) and got it working. Yet I am still not sure why this specific code won't work, so I'll keep the question.

Hello.

I am writing a small puzzle game in Java (using Eclipse 4.4.2) and stumbled upon a problem inside one of my methods. Basically - it won't complete the method, it just exits the method after the for loop is done without any warnings or errors (I'm not catching exceptions either). I hope I missed something simple..

Details:

I have a method to set the colors of an object and up to 5 other objects that are linked to it through lines. I set up the color of the main object, then find the linked objects through for-loops and in the end change their colors as well. (Double checked the code for Lines, there are simple return methods and nestA and nestB as data - no problem there). lines is an array with a length of 50, nests as its members.

Here's the code:

```
public void highlightNests(Nest nest) {

    //setting the color of the main object (a nest).
    Mappers.setColor(nest, nestHighlight);

    //resetting the array. Temp solution, had a return method earlier, 
    //this is part of the debugging.
    connectedNests = null;
    connectedNests = new Nest[5];

    int i = 0;
    Gdx.app.log("highlightNests()", "starting the loop");

    for (int j=0; j<lines.length; j++) {
        if (lines[j].getNestA() == nest) {
            connectedNests[i] = lines[j].getNestB();
            i++;
        }
        if (lines[j].getNestB() == nest) {
            connectedNests[i] = lines[j].getNestA();
            i++;
        }

    }
    //This is where the program exits the method. The following  
    //lines are not run.
    Gdx.app.log("highlightNests()", "entering loop");
    for (int l=0; i<connectedNests.length; l++) {
        Mappers.setColor(connectedNests[l], nestHighlight);
        Gdx.app.log("highlightNests",  "set color");
    }

}
```

Deleting the middle section makes the end part run, so there are no errors in the last part.

Comment: There are a number of problems with this code. Your second loop will either run infinitely or not at all as you are checking against `i` without changing it within the loop.

Comment: are you sure you want `i`in your second loop? (not `l` ?)

Comment: Also, there is a chance in your "middle" for to increase i twice per iteration (or maybe not, depends on the logic of getNestA/B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second loop is completely wrong, you declare the counter as `l` and increment another counter `i`, you should use `l<connectedNests.length` change it like this:

```
for (int l=0; l<connectedNests.length; l++) {
    Mappers.setColor(connectedNests[l], nestHighlight);
    Gdx.app.log("highlightNests",  "set color");
}
```

And the program  won't finish method and exits before the loop because, it doesn't even enter the loop as it's incorrect.

Comment: Oh god. You are completely right. I knew it had to be something simple, just had to get someone else to point it out. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `l` instead of `i` in condition like,

```
for (int l=0; l<connectedNests.length; l++)...
   //---------^ l not i
```

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have questions for the op try a comment or chat.